# World To Screenspace for Mode7 effect (fragment shader)

Tags: opengl, math, algebra

I have a fragment shader that transforms the view into something resembling mode7.
I want to know the Screen-Space x,y coordinates given a world position.
As the transformation happens in the fragment shader, I can't simply inverse a matrix. This is the fragment shader code:

```
uniform float Fov; //1.4
uniform float Horizon; //0.6
uniform float Scaling; //0.8

void main() {
    vec2 pos = uv.xy - vec2(0.5, Horizon);
    vec3 p = vec3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.y + Fov);
    vec2 s = vec2(p.x/p.z, p.y/p.z) * Scaling;

    s.x += 0.5;
    s.y += screenRatio;

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(ColorTexture, s);
}
```

It transforms pixels in a pseudo 3d way:

[image: Mode 7 Pic]

-
What I want to do is get a screen-space coordinate for a given world position (in normal code, not shaders).
How do I reverse the order of operations above?

This is what I have right now:
(GAME_WIDTH and GAME_HEIGHT are constants and hold pixel values, e.g. 320x240)

```
vec2 WorldToScreenspace(float x, float y) {
    // normalize coordinates 0..1, as x,y are in pixels
    x = x/GAME_WIDTH - 0.5;
    y = y/GAME_HEIGHT - Horizon;

    // as z depends on a y value I have yet to calculate, how can I calc it?
    float z = ??;

    // invert: vec2 s = vec2(p.x/p.z, p.y/p.z) * Scaling;
    float sx = x*z / Scaling;
    float sy = y*z / Scaling;

    // invert: pos = uv.xy - vec2(0.5, Horizon);
    sx += 0.5;
    sy += screenRatio;

    // convert back to screen space
    return new vec2(sx * GAME_WIDTH, sy * GAME_HEIGHT);
}
```

Comment: "As the transformation happens in the fragment shader, I can't simply inverse a matrix.". Why not? the transformation you do in the FS is just representable as a uniform standard homogeneous transform matrix, and so is its inverse. Also, using `textureProj` familiy of functions would lead to the most efficient way to do the perspective divide in your scenario.

Comment: why not pass world coordinates (un-transformed) to fragment too ... also see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)  so (pseudo)inverse matrix is also an option

Comment: @derhass I am not really sure how I would go about that.
My framework doesnt allow access to the vertex shader, can I pass that into the fragment shader?

Comment: also, my game doesn't really use matrixes internally and i am not that familiar with them. i wouldn't know how to represent my shader as a transformation matrix. but thanks for the link.